# If $\sin(\beta+\gamma)= \sin\epsilon$ and $\cos\beta\cos\gamma<\sin\beta\sin\gamma$, then $\beta+\gamma=\pi-\epsilon$

Tags: trigonometry, education

I have the following system:

$$\begin{align}
\sin\beta \,\cos\gamma + \cos\beta\,\sin\gamma &= \sin\epsilon \\
\cos\beta\,\cos\gamma &< \sin\beta\,\sin\gamma
\end{align}$$

In other terms:

$$\begin{align}
\sin(\beta+\gamma) &= \sin \epsilon \\
\cos\beta \,\cos\gamma &< \sin\beta\,\sin\gamma
\end{align}$$

Can you explain me why $\beta+\gamma=\pi-\epsilon$, please?

---

EDIT: I know also that $\epsilon$ belongs to $[-\pi /2, \pi /2]$.

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Clearly that is a possible solution to the first equation. Clearly also there are insufficient constraints stated in your question to make it the only possibility. Do these angles come from a triangle, for example? Is anything else known about the context?

Comment: Hello @MarkBennet, I am studying the cardan angles. The above result comes from the slides of my professor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality says $\cos(\beta+\gamma)<0$. So your problem is that of finding the relations between $A$ and $B$ in the following:
\begin{align*}
\sin A & =\sin B\\
\cos A &<0.
\end{align*}
From the first equation, we get $A=n\pi+(-1)^nB$. In the interval $[0,2\pi)$ we have $A=B$ or $A=\pi-B$.

If we further know something about the angle $B$ (for example, if it is in $[0,\pi/2]$), then with $\cos A <0$, we can conclude that $A=\pi-B$.

So in your problem, depending on what you know about $\epsilon$, the conclusion can be inferred from that.

Comment: Hello @AnuragA can you see my edit please? With these additional constraints is it possible to infer my result?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi constraint on $\gamma$ and $\beta$ will not narrow down the possibilities I have stated in my answer. Some condition on $\epsilon$ is needed.

Comment: thank you very much for your precious help.

Comment: Hi @AnuragA, I edit my question: i know the range of $\epsilon$. In this case can I prove the above result?